# What does the less than symbol in front of LVM volume size mean?

Tags: lvm

### Input

```
lvs
```

### Output

```
LV   VG     Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
home mainvg -wi-ao----  10.00g
root mainvg -wi-ao---- <40.00g
swap swapvg -wi-ao----   4.00g
```

What does the less than symbol (`<`) in the `root` volume size mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From `man lvs`:

> --units r|R|h|H|b|B|s|S|k|K|m|M|g|G|t|T|p|P|e|E
>                 All sizes are output in these units: human-(r)eadable with '<' rounding indicator

Comment: Thank you.  I guess I need to remember to use the system man pages since [the one I looked at](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lvs) didn't match my system.